# How to fix "Destructuring component props breaks Solid's reactivity" warning?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jsx, solid-js

I am new to SolidJS and I have the following UI

```
import { render } from "solid-js/web";
import { createSignal, Show } from "solid-js";
import { createStore } from 'solid-js/store';



function Form() {

  const [state, setState] = createStore([{status: false}]);

  function onClick() {
    if (state[0].status) {
        setState([{status:  false}])
        console.log("false")
    } else {
        setState([{status: true}])
        console.log("true")
    }
  }

    return(
        <div>
            <Checkbox state={state} onClick={onClick}/>
        </div>
    )
}

function Checkbox({state, onClick}) {
    return(
      <div onClick={onClick}>
        <Show when={state}>
            <div>To be shown when enabled</div>
        </Show>

        <Show when={!state}>
            <div>To be shown when disabled</div>
        </Show>
        </div>
    )
}

render(() => <Form />, document.getElementById("app")!);
```

The SolidJS Playground gives me the following warning: `Destructuring component props breaks Solid's reactivity; use property access instead. eslint(solid/no-destructure)` and clicking on the element does not change state.

How do I pass the click handler and the `state` prop as an argument to the `Checkbox` function?

Comment: The message is pretty clear though, instead of `function Checkbox({state, onClick}) {` simply write `function Checkbox(props) {` this is one limitation of SolidJS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is prop destructuring, by destructuring you are opting out of reactivity:

```js
function Checkbox({state, onClick}){}
```

You should use it directly:

```js
function Checkbox(props) {
  return(
    <div onClick={props.onClick}>
      <Show when={props.state}>
        <div>To be shown when enabled</div>
      </Show>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use this if you realy want it:

```
type DestructedParams<T extends object> = {
    [K in keyof T]-?: Accessor<T[K]>
}

const useDestructure = <T extends object>(params: T) => new Proxy(params, {
    get(obj, key) {
        return () => obj[key as keyof T];
    },
}) as DestructedParams<T>

function Checkbox(props) {
  const {state, onClick, ...others} = useDestructure(props)

  return(
    <div onClick={ onClick() }>
      <Show when={ state() }>
        <div>To be shown when enabled</div>
      </Show>
    </div>
  )
}
```

this converts all properties to an signal accessor